# Not able to select through CSS Selector from webdriver

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am Unable to find the element with containing the "Confirm" and  "Cancel".
Also, dont want to use Xpath. Can anyone suggest me the best approach to get the element.
Below is the HTML -

```
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
   <button class="btn-confirm-dialog ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-  button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Confirm</span>
   </button>
   <button class="btn-confirm-dialog ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
   </button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got this through the "nth-child" Property of `cssSelector`.

```
Confirm =>  div.ui-dialog-buttonset> button:nth-child(1) >Span

Cancel => div.ui-dialog-buttonset> button:nth-child(2) >Span
```

Thanks for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select elements by it's text with css.
Try these css selectors:
Confirm: `button span` ,though cancel button also matches this, WebDriver.findElement method stops when it finds the first matching element.
Cancel: `button + button span`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html design to have the link (`<a href="xxx">...</a>`) inside of the button tag. Than you can get webelement using selenium locator "By Link Text"
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations

Answer (score 0):

Confirm Button -- css=button.btn-confirm-dialog > span:contains("Confirm")
Cancel Button -- css=button.btn-confirm-dialog > span:contains("Cancel")

The above are the CSS selectors for Confirm and Cancel buttons.